# Share a part of google drive on Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, shared-directory

We are sharing a google drive folder where we put the colab notebooks. Now we need to upload some text files **permanently** for notebook usage. I do not want to upload files every time I open colab. From what I searched, I had to upload files to google drive and mount it to colab in some way.
So, when I mount google drive to colab, can my teammates access **all** my files in it, or simply the shared folder.
If not, is there a way to share only a folder or a file of google drive in colab.

Answer (score 9):

If you [share a folder with your teammates in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529) then that folder will appear in each of their drive mounts in colab. Each person running code in a notebook (even if they share a notebook) gets their own VM. One person should never see another person's Drive mount.

An alternative to sharing a data-file folder in Drive is to upload your data to GCS and have your notebook fetch it from there ([example](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=S7c8WYyQdh5i)).